# How can I control the order in which make targets are executed?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a main target, `exe` which depends on three libs:

```
exe: LIB1.lib LIB2.lib LIB3.lib
```

and the lib targets have something like this:

```
LIB1: $(LIB1OBJECTS)
LIB2: $(LIB2OBJECTS)
LIB3: $(LIB3OBJECTS)
```

Giving that most of the time, make will be run with a `-j` flag, and I would like for LIB1 and LIB2 to be built in parallel, how can I make sure that LIB3 is always built after LIB2?

Comment: I would have expected the rules to go like `LIB1.lib: $(LIB1OBJECTS)`, rather than `LIB1: $(LIB1OBJECTS)`. Maybe this mixture of names is why Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' suggestion doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make LIB3 dependent on LIB2.

Comment: Can I make it depend on LIB2 and on the objects as well? I tried putting something like `LIB3: $(LIB3OBJECTS) LIB2`, but something must be wrong, because sometimes it starts building LIB3 without waiting for LIB2 to be finished.

Comment: You should be able to. Are any of them used in other targets?

Comment: @Geo: That's fine - with that rule, it will first build `$(LIB3OBJECTS)`,then `LIB2`.